# Exception for the "instance (Num a) => YesNo a where" code row

Tags: haskell

This works fine:

```
class YesNo a where
    yesNo :: a-> Bool

instance YesNo Bool where
    yesNo True = True
    yesNo _ = False

instance YesNo [a] where
    yesNo [] = False
    yesNo _ = True

instance YesNo (Maybe a) where
    yesNo Nothing = False
    yesNo _ = True
```

But I get an error for the code:

```
instance (Num a) => YesNo a where -- error is here
    yesNo 0 = False
    yesNo _ = True
```

Exception message:

```
ghci> :l src
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( src.hs, interpreted )

src.hs:16:21:
    Illegal instance declaration for `YesNo a'
      (All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)
       where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*,
       and each type variable appears at most once in the instance head.
       Use FlexibleInstances if you want to disable this.)
    In the instance declaration for `YesNo a'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
ghci>
```

What I did incorrect?

Comment: All functions can be simplified. For `Bool`: `yesNo = id`, for `[a]`: `yesNo = not . empty`, for `Maybe a`: `yesNo = isJust`.

Comment: @Jeffrey `yesNo = not . null`

Comment: @augustss Yeah, I keep forgetting it's `null` and not `empty`. I just seem to have a deep aversion for the term "`null`".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message already indicates, there are `ghc` options that make your instance declaration perfectly legal (you will have to add a constraint `Eq a` to it, though, if your ghc is [newer than 7.4.1](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/1jyzuj/is_the_num_typeclass_supposed_to_be_a_a_subclass/))

```
ghci -XFlexibleInstances -XUndecidableInstances <your program>
```

will compile and work in the way you expect.

Why are flexible and undecidable instances not allowed by default?

- Type classes are *open*, they can be extended at any later moment. Suppose someone else would extend `Num` with an `instance (Num a) => Num [a])`, with for example `fromInt x = [fromInt x]` and componentwise addition, etc. Then we would have overlapping instances: shoud `yesNo [0]` be `True` or `False`? So by extending one class (`Num`) instances of some other class (`YesNo`) are suddenly overlapping. This is why *flexible* instances are not allowed by default
- When declaring `instance (Eq a, Num a) => YesNo a`, `Num a` is not strictly smaller (simpler) than `YesNo a`. You and I know that checking any type for `YesNo`-ness will eventually yield an aswer, but suppose, again, that someone else (why not?) would add an instance `(YesNo a) => Num a where..`. Then the type checker would get stuck in a loop: `YesNo a => Num a => YesNo a ...`  This is why (potentially) *undecidable* instances are not allowed by default

So, overriding the default restrictions on type class definitions may well work now, but can cause severe head-scratching in the future.

Comment: It [won't actually work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ccaa88cf150a2d1) "the way you expect". In fact it won't even compile.

Comment: @Jefffrey Can you describe what it will actually do?

Comment: Correct, the instance declaration needs to be (trivially) constrained a bit more: `instance (Eq a, Num a) => YesNo a`.

Answer (score 5):

It appears that you're trying to make it so that every type which is an instance of `Num` is automatically an instance of `YesNo`.

Unfortunately, you can't do that.

You can only declare an instance for a *specific type*. So you can declare an instance for `Int` or `Double`, but you can't declare an instance for "every `Num`".

Comment: I.e. must I to write implimentation for the `Int`, `Integer`, `Float` and `Double` separately? It is not convinient... :(

Comment: @Bush Yes. Annoying, isn't it?

Comment: Is it not possible to define this instance if you only use functions *specific* to the `Num` typeclass? Try `fromInteger 0` instead of `0`.

Comment: Note that you can use `DefaultSignatures` to write the *implementation* exactly once, and then simply write `instance X Int; instance X Double; instance X Integer; ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
instance (Num a) => YesNo a where
    yesNo x | x == fromIntegral 0 = False
            | otherwise = True
```

The problem is that `0` is not of type `a`.
In any instance of `Num`, however, you have to define a `fromIntegral` function.

Comment: Numeric literals are overloaded in Haskell - an integer literal `n` (like `0`) is equivalent to `fromIntegral n`, with type `(Num a) => a`. This means that your instance declaration is essentially the same as the original one, and needs the same additional constraint (`Eq a`) and compiler options to work

Comment: Aha.
Can you explain to me why you can define an instance:
    
    `instance Ord a,b => Ord (a,b)` ...

but not this one...

Comment: `Ord (a,b)` is of the form `classname (T a b)` (where the constructor `T` is the pairing operator), while `Yesno a` is of the form `classname a`. This "wrapping" of the type variables in a constructor prevents the problems with flexible instances as well as with undecidable instances (see my answer)

Comment: Wauw, I suddenly got it.
You just taught me something!
Thank you even so much! Should I leave this here or delete the answer?

Comment: I'm not sure what is best in such a case. You could  [search](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=delete+own+answer) (or ask) Meta Slashdot for an answer?